# HDFS connection from Excel Power Query

Tags: excel, hadoop, hdfs, ms-office, powerquery

Have a server with a Hadoop instance running on it.

Basically I'd like to connect to some HDFS table via Excel on my local machine. I know that Power Query Add-in helps in dealing that operation and provide an opportunity to establish connection with HDFS. But here is the thing-I have Excel 2016, so according to Microsoft Documentation, Power Query is already built in the Excel. But when I'm trying to do "Data-Get Data-From Other Sources" there is simply no option like "Get Data from From Hadoop File (HDFS)"

What am I doing wrong and what exact steps do I need to take to get access to HDFS from Excel?

Comment: Do you mean Hive or HDFS? HDFS itself has no concept of tables

Comment: I meant for example parquet files in HDFS storage system

Comment: Sure, though, you can define Hive tables over Parquet data and use any ODBC/JDBC connection with the correct drivers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me HDFS shows up here:
[image: Hadoop]

but not here:
[image: No Hadoop]

What does the first New Query > From Other Sources look like for you?

Comment: Exact the same like yours except that fact that Import from HDFS is not exist((